# How do I convert 3-hour precipitation data from GLDAS 2.0 to mm/day in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I convert 3 hours of precipitation data from GLDAS 2.0 to mm/day?The data is in kg/m^2/s in GEE and I want to get the daily precipitation (mm/day). How do I do this?

The data description says.
*Provider's Note: the names with extension _tavg are variables averaged over the past 3-hours*

I can't understand "the names with extension _tavg are variables averaged over the past 3-hours".

So how do I write the code to get the daily precipitation in roi?

```
var roi = yours roi;
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-05-01', '2022-06-02'))
                .select(['Rainf_f_tavg']);

var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: dataset5,
          region: roi,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['precipitation'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'precipitation',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Vegetation index (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 8 images per day so, you should to convert them in a daily series. Following code does that for my considered roi. As **Rainf_f_tavg** units are kg/m^2/s, you need to transform them in mm/day. kg/m^2 is equivalent to mm. As it is returned a sum of filterCol (with 8 images), the corresponding factor should be 86400/8 = 10800 (please, search for the possibility of other factor as 3600).

```
Map.centerObject(roi);

var iniDate = ee.Date('2022-05-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2022-06-02');

var difdate = endDate.advance(-1, 'day').difference(iniDate, 'day'); //calculate steps/days in between 
var createList = ee.List.sequence(0, difdate); //make list with the needed number of entries

var listdates = createList.map(function(day){ //change list into list of dates

  return iniDate.advance(day, 'day');
  
});

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
                .filter(ee.Filter.date(iniDate, endDate))
                .select(['Rainf_f_tavg']);

print(dataset);

var dailyDataset  = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listdates.map(function(summarize_day){
    var filterCol = dataset.filterDate(ee.Date(summarize_day), ee.Date(summarize_day).advance(1, 'day'));

    return filterCol.sum().select(['Rainf_f_tavg'])
                          .multiply(10800)
                          .copyProperties(filterCol.first()).setMulti({
                            Date: ee.Date(summarize_day), 
                            'system:time_start': ee.Date(summarize_day).millis()});})
                          
);

print(dailyDataset);

var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: dailyDataset,
          region: roi,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['precipitation'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Daily precipitation',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Precipitation (mm)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });

print(chart.setChartType('ColumnChart'));
```

After running [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c7eb752a2fdefbec654d5bc68605c9b7) in GEE code editor, it was produced the following result:

[image]